# Why does my explicit cursor fetch only specific rows from my database in PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, cursor, fetch

I am very new to PL/SQL and I am trying to use an explicit cursor to iterate over my database, FLEX_PANEL_INSPECTIONS. I would like to fetch each row from the database in turn using an explicit cursor, and depending on the randomly generated 'status' of a given 'panel' in the row, assign the panel a new status value within an if / else statement. The status of the panel is random but Boolean - it is either 1 or 0.
However, when I view the DBMS output, I note that the fetch does not retrieve all values from the database - only those who have a status value of 1. I have included the core code below.
I would be very grateful if anybody is able to help me find a solution, or explain the root cause of my problem, thanks!

```
create or replace procedure FLEX_SUMMARY_STATUS_PROCEDURE as

old_panel_status number;
new_panel_status number;

cursor panel_cursor is
    select FLEX_PANEL_STATUS
    from FLEX_PANEL_INSPECTIONS;

begin

    open panel_cursor;
    loop

        fetch panel_cursor into old_panel_status;
        exit when panel_cursor%notfound;

        if old_panel_status = 0
            then new_panel_status := 2;
        elsif old_panel_status = 1
            then new_panel_status := 3;
        --More conditional loops follow (but are irrelevant for this question).

        dbms_output.put_line(old_panel_status);
        --Test output
        --This displays all of the 1's that were randomly generated in the original table.
        --It does not display any of the 0's that were generated.

        end if;
    end loop;

close panel_cursor;
close sensor_cursor;

end FLEX_SUMMARY_STATUS_PROCEDURE;
/
```

Comment: You dbms_output in `if old_panel_status = 1` block ! Maybe move `end if;` UP and before dbms_ouput ?

Comment: `dbms_output` is within the *else* clause. So it only prints those with status = 1. Your code identation indicates you would like to have it outside the if/then/else.

Comment: And please stop using the outdated open/loop/fetch/exit construct. It's verbose and causes problems. Instead, use the much more elegant `FOR rec IN cursor LOOP ... END LOOP`.

Comment: This is a good example of why **good, consistent** code indentation is so important!  I just posted and deleted a comment saying this couldn't be happening, because I believed the misleading indentation and thought we'd already had the `end if;`!

Comment: Hi chaps, thanks for answering so quickly!

Comment: You are right - moving the dbms output line shows that the values are assigned correctly. To get all the desired data out of the loop, where must I put my insert into.. select statement? Thanks

Comment: Codo - as I explained, I have only spent 5 days learning PL/SQL. Please could you explain the new construct a bit more so I can use it in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you didn't make a mistake when removing the additional elseif clauses, the issue is in the location of your dbms_output.put_line.

It's located inside the else part, so will only trigger when this clause is called. Move it below the END IF and make sure to use proper indentation, which makes such things way easier to spot.

```
create or replace procedure FLEX_SUMMARY_STATUS_PROCEDURE as

old_panel_status number;
new_panel_status number;

cursor panel_cursor is
    select FLEX_PANEL_STATUS
    from FLEX_PANEL_INSPECTIONS;

begin

    open panel_cursor;
    loop

        fetch panel_cursor into old_panel_status;
        exit when panel_cursor%notfound;

        if old_panel_status = 0
            then new_panel_status := 2;
        elsif old_panel_status = 1
            then new_panel_status := 3;
        --More conditional loops follow (but are irrelevant for this question)
        end if;

    dbms_output.put_line(old_panel_status);

    end loop;

    close panel_cursor;
    close sensor_cursor;

end FLEX_SUMMARY_STATUS_PROCEDURE;
/
```

Comment: Thank you - I have edited my original post to show the correct indentation

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the main error, which has already been fixed in the accepted answer, the below code shows the newer loop construct. Instead of `rec`, you can choose any variable name you like. On each iteration, it contains a row (usually with more than one column).

```
create or replace procedure FLEX_SUMMARY_STATUS_PROCEDURE as

new_panel_status number;

cursor panel_cursor is
    select FLEX_PANEL_STATUS
    from FLEX_PANEL_INSPECTIONS;

begin

    for rec in panel_cursor loop

        if rec.flex_panel_status = 0 then
            new_panel_status := 2;
        elsif rec.flex_panel_status = 1 then
            new_panel_status := 3;
        --More conditional loops follow (but are irrelevant for this question)
        end if;

        dbms_output.put_line(rec.flex_panel_status);

    end loop;

end FLEX_SUMMARY_STATUS_PROCEDURE;
/
```

You can even get rid if the explicit cursor if you like:

```
for rec in (
    select FLEX_PANEL_STATUS
    from FLEX_PANEL_INSPECTIONS
) loop
```

Comment: Much better. I'm not sure cursor FOR loops are 'newer' than the open-loop-fetch-exit-lose-will-to-live construct though, if we're talking about Oracle releases.